# Adding two Points together in OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv

I currently have a rectangle (of type `Rect`), which I'm trying to find the central coordinate to. I know that I can find the top left point by typing:

`rectangle.tl();`

and the bottom right by typing:

`rectangle.br();`

However, I need to be able to add these values together (before halving them) to find the central coordinate. The `+` operator doesn't work for `Point` - and I can't find anything which explains addition in the `Point` documentation. Could someone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> Template class for 2D rectangles, described by the following
>   parameters:
>
> Coordinates of the top-left corner. This is a default interpretation of Rect_::x and Rect_::y in OpenCV. Though, in your
>   algorithms you may count x and y from the bottom-left corner.
>       Rectangle width and height.

Reference : http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html

Now you can find centroid by formula
x =  rect.x + (rect.width/2);
y =  rect.y + (rect.height/2);